# Move from Ubuntu 18.10 to Kubuntu 18.04 while keeping /home directory

Tags: kubuntu

I'd like to move from Ubuntu 18.10 to Kubuntu 18.04. I've already flashed the Kubuntu ISO to a USB stick, but when I get to the partitioning stage in the Kubuntu installer, there's nothing about reinstalling or keeping the /home directory. Please don't suggest the 'backup files to USB storage device, install over Ubuntu, and then move files over again' method. I don't have any large enough USB storage devices for me to do that. Also, my /home directory is not stored on a separate partition to the one Ubuntu is installed on. Does anyone know how to move from Ubuntu to Kubuntu without losing the /home directory?

Comment: If you use 'something else', and replace your existing Ubuntu ensuring you do not select 'format', it'll erase all system directories but not /home (which isn't a system directory!).  The installer will take note of what apps you had installed and try and restore them post-install.  You should however still backup your data before hand, because it's easy to make a mistake & 'format' your partition (it's a check box you don't want ticked).

Comment: @guiverc - is that the case even when there is only one partition `/` without a `/home` separate partition?

Comment: @ PerlDuck - the comment above seems to say that even without a separate *partition* `/home`, if "format" is not selected the  *directory* `/home` on the single `/` partition will be kept. Is that true?

Comment: @cipricus Yes, it sounds so but I wouldn't rely on it without having a backup of my `/home` -- which the OP apparently has not.

Comment: @cipricus I've done it many times and not lost any data.  I'd still not do it without a backup though; as it's very easy to miss the tiny 'format' checkbox, or make a mistake.  The biggest limit of my knowledge is 18.10 to 18.04 (I've not moved to Kubuntu from Ubuntu in years, and likewise haven't backwards installed in years which is why I've not written it as an answer. I have however re-installed without losing data at least twice within last 9 months. *Most of my installs these days are QA-tests, which do not backwards install*.  Because it's possible does not mean you shouldn't backup.

Comment: @guiverc - you should post as an answer anyway, as I don't think there is any other solution, while mentioning that switching desktops involves supplementary risks. But your solution is what the OP asks for.

Comment: @PerlDuck - as **backup is always a must** AND the OP says `Please don't suggest the 'backup files etc` - I see no other way.

Comment: Note that any installation procedure involves risks that justify the backup requirement. Dismissing that you cannot ask for a risk-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly do a backup (and maybe a second if your data is important if you don't already have it). Changing or installing and operating system isn't a minor task and you could have a power-outage, power-surge or any number of things go wrong during the long process, even if unlikely.*

I would suggest using 'something else', and select your existing partition for you Kubuntu. Key is to ensure you do not select 'format'.  This option will erase all system directories (/bin, /sbin..)  but not /home (which isn't a system directory!).

The installer takes note of your [manually] installed apps and will try and restore (as in re-install) them post-install.

Making a backup is important, the most likely error in my experience is wrongly having the 'format' check-box ticked (it's small & easily overlooked).

*Caveats: I have done it heaps of times and not lost any data. My usual 'installs' are not backwards, though I've done that too, alas not recently. I've also not replaced Ubuntu with Kubuntu recently. I have also not tried 18.10 to 18.04, but going backwards does contain more pitfalls than moving forwards (which is QA-tested).  Software upgrades that occur in versions can cause differences in user config files (in your /home/user/ directory) that can confuse earlier versions of software. I've experienced this long ago with `evolution` (my chosen email client or 'mua'). I started using a 'new' feature in the later release, the earlier release didn't know about it & had minor issues with the change in data in files. I don't know what programs you used extensively in 18.10 that contain 'new' features stored in files that you'll be loosing in 18.04 that may cause issues for you; but in most cases you won't be 'bitten' - but it's a potential risk.*

*Most important is your backup though!.  Even though you're not likely to touch it, it's an insurance policy with minimal cost.*

Comment: I don't really want my installed packages to come with me. Only my /home folder.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to stop packages following you is to 'format' your / partition (which won't affect /home if it's on it's own partition, as there is no check-box for that).  You don't have that option as I understand it as you have your /home [folder] located on your / partition  (this is one example where a separate home partition helps; an extra choice). I think it's a great feature [restoring packages]; as usually most people are re-installing the same version, and it saves them from having to do as much setup to get back where they were.  Your logs will show what was re-installed.

Comment: The is no option "Something else" in the Kubuntu 22.04 installation image. Is it the "manual" option? Unfortunately the next screen one sees after the "manual" choice is very complex for a novice, with a list of partitions and options to add, change, delete...

Comment: Kubuntu uses a KDE-Qt5 skin on `ubiquity` which changes the name, and it looks a lot more like the option in Lubuntu or *modern* Ubuntu-Studio using `calamares`, ie. *Manual Partitioning*.  The option is there, you just select existing partitions and ensure the partition(s) aren't formatted. The plan is for an easier way to do it with the *canary* installer (what will become the new *Ubuntu Desktop Installer*) but it cannot currently do this yet. No add/delete is used, only change, set mount point & check 'format' checkbox isn't ticked/crossed. This needs to be done for all partitions used